# For Each Loop in a Set

Tags: java, set, maps

I have a HashTable with the following `{4:1, 3:56, 4:3, 4:5, 9:89, etc.}`

I then make the keys of this Table into a keyset by calling `map.keySet()`.

**How can I loop through that set to only output the values associated with the key of 4?** I want the output to be `1,3,5,` therefore I only want the values associated with the key 4? Is this possible, and if so how.

Comment: Hashmap does not allow multiple values for a key. What exactly are you using? Can you show your code?

Comment: I'm using a HashTable sorry.

Comment: btw even hashtable does not allow that

Answer (score 0):

That's not how maps work. Maps typically only associate one value with each unique key value. So if you have a `Map<Integer,Integer> myMap`, calling `myMap.put(4, newValue)`, where `newValue` is some integer, will overwrite the value that was previously mapped to `4`. You can have duplicate values though, and you can print all known keys that have been mapped to that value in a map using the following loop.

```
for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().equals(4)) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A HashMap or a HashTable only maps *a key* to *a value*.

**Option 1:**

If you want to have multiple values for key store it as a list

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<>();

//To add value for a key
if (!myMap.containsKey(key)) {
    myMap.put(new ArrayList<>());
}
myMap.get(key).add(value);

//Get
myMap.get(key); //This will give you the list of value for a given key and null if the key is not present
```

**Option 2:**

You can use Google Guava's [MultiMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Guava Collections' MultiMap as it allows each key to associate with multiple values.

`ListMultimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
 multimap.put(key, value);`

Documentation can be found here: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html